# Why I cannot connect my order error page to my Django website?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to build an ecommerce site, but I don't understand how you can connect the order error page to the website.

I've tried adding a window.location.replace to the JavaScript file after the .then function in the result.error section.

```
}).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    console.log('payment error')
                    console.log(result.error.message);

                    window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/error/");
                } else {
                    if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                        console.log('payment processed')

                        window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/orderplaced/");
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},
```

I've also tried adding an if else function beneath the succeeded.

```
}).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    console.log('payment error')
                    console.log(result.error.message);
                } else {
                    if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                        console.log('payment processed')

                        window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/orderplaced/");
                    } else {
                        if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'failed') {
                            console.log('payment error')

                            window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},
```

I've tried editing the Error class to a define, but it didn't work out within the payment views.py. I've tried creating a new define called error and made the orders urls.py connect to the new error defined, but nothing happened when I try to put a declined credit card information.

My payment views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):
    payload = request.body
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Event.construct_from(
            json.loads(payload), stripe.api_key
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    if event.type == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        payment_confirmation(event.data.object.client_secret)

    else:
        print('Unhandled event type {}'.format(event.type))

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

```
class Error(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'payment/error.html'
```

Comment: It's not clear what the actual issue is from your message. 

> nothing happened when I try to put a declined credit card information.

So the URL doesn't change to `/payment/error/`?

Is that page loading: http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/error/ ?

What shows in the browser console? And what shows in your terminal (where runserver is running) when you try?

Comment: No, the URL doesn't change to /payment/error/ and it also doesn't show up that html page. The error I get is shared-2354fafdd3602f09440ff8e44147b74b.js:1          POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_3M6jNXEeX9bmWjgu0aglPRdM/confirm 402 in the browser console. On the terminal it says "Unhandled event type payment_intent.payment_failed.

Comment: I see, so in your JS code, you probably want handle errors under `error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},`  or maybe it's out of that `then` part. It's hard to say with the code extract you gave. But basically, you need to catch that 402 within JS...